# Why does the Message Box appear without color or style?

Tags: sapui5

I try to create message box with two buttons, one called English and the second called German, to select one of these languages. The names of button should be called from i18n file. I should to write this code only in Component.js file. The Problem is that the message box appears without colors or style. I had tried so much Samples but the same problem appear. also when I had tried to use style.css file!! You can see the photos, one which I want to make like it and the other what I made.

maybe someone can help please?

Thank you

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/m/ResponsivePopover",
    "sap/m/MessageBox"
], function(UIComponent, ResponsivePopover, MessageBox) {
    "use strict";
    MessageBox.information(
        "Select One Of These Languages Please.", {
            actions: ["ENGLISCH", "DEUTSCH"],
            title: "Language Selection",
            emphasizedAction: "ENGLISCH",
            onClose: function (oAction) {}
            

        }
    );
    return UIComponent.extend("com.example.FLPPlugins.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */

     
        init: function() {
            this._langswPopover;
            var renderer = sap.ushell.Container.getRenderer("fiori2");
            renderer.addHeaderEndItem("sap.ushell.ui.shell.ShellHeadItem", {
                id: "langswButton",
                icon: "sap-icon://world",
                press: this._showLangsw.bind(this)
            }, true, false);

        
           
        },
       
      _showLangsw: function(oEvent) {
            var oLangswButton = oEvent.getSource();
            var oDeButton;
            var oEnButton;
            if(this._langswPopover === undefined) {
                this._langswPopover = new ResponsivePopover({
                    title: this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("title"),
                    placement: "Bottom",
                    afterClose: this.onCloseLangsw.bind(this)
                });
                var oFlexBox = new sap.m.FlexBox({
                    direction: "Column",
                    alignItems: "Start"
                });
                var langu = sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLanguage();
                switch(langu) {
                    case 'DE':
                    case 'de':
                    case 'de-DE':
                        oDeButton = new sap.m.Button({
                            id: 'de-DE',
                            text: this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("deButtonText"),
                            press: this.onPressButton.bind(this),
                            enabled: false
                        });
                        oEnButton = new sap.m.Button({
                            id: 'en-EN',
                            text: this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("enButtonText"),
                            press: this.onPressButton.bind(this)
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'EN':
                    case 'en':
                    case 'en-EN':
                        oDeButton = new sap.m.Button({
                            id: 'de-DE',
                            text: this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("deButtonText"),
                            press: this.onPressButton.bind(this)
                        });
                        oEnButton = new sap.m.Button({
                            id: 'en-EN',
                            text: this.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("enButtonText"),
                            press: this.onPressButton.bind(this),
                            enabled: false
                        });
                        break;
                }
                oFlexBox.addItem(oDeButton);
                oFlexBox.addItem(oEnButton);
                this._langswPopover.addContent(oFlexBox);
                this._langswPopover.addStyleClass("sapUiResponsiveContentPadding");
                this._langswPopover.openBy(oLangswButton);
            } else {
                this.onCloseLangsw();
            }
        },
        onPressButton: function(oEvent) {
            var language = oEvent.getSource().getId();
            var langu = language.split('-');
            jQuery.sap.storage.put("langChange", true);
            window.location.search = 'sap-language=' + langu[1];
            sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage(langu);
            this.onCloseLangsw();
        },
        onCloseLangsw: function() {
            this._langswPopover.destroy();
            this._langswPopover = undefined;
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just the difference in theme? Top his Horizon, bottom is Quartz